# Response Code=-1011 "Request failed: unsupported media type (415)

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, freshdesk

I want to call API of "freshdesk" using AFNetworking. And that API is working perfectly from rest client.But I want to call that API from iOS application side using AFNetworking But I getting below error:

```
Error Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1011 "Request failed: unsupported media type (415)" UserInfo={com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.response=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7fd4a1579ed0> { URL: https://leotest.freshdesk.com/api/v2/tickets } { status code: 415, headers {
    Connection = "keep-alive";
    "Content-Length" = 145;
    "Content-Type" = "application/json";
    Date = "Fri, 09 Dec 2016 04:45:22 GMT";
    Status = "415 Unsupported Media Type";
    "X-Rack-Cache" = "invalidate, pass";
    "X-RateLimit-Remaining" = 4966;
    "X-RateLimit-Total" = 5000;
    "X-RateLimit-Used-CurrentRequest" = 1;
    "X-Request-Id" = e3f6a1bcd872f476d1701ce0dd7b5f54;
} }, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://leotest.freshdesk.com/api/v2/tickets, com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.data=<7b22636f 6465223a 22696e76 616c6964 5f636f6e 74656e74 5f747970 65222c22 6d657373 61676522 3a22436f 6e74656e 742d5479 70652068 65616465 72206973 20736574 20746f20 6170706c 69636174 696f6e2f 782d7777 772d666f 726d2d75 726c656e 636f6465 642e2049 74207368 6f756c64 20626520 73657420 746f2061 70706c69 63617469 6f6e2f6a 736f6e22 7d>, NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: unsupported media type (415)}
```

I think problem is that when I'm passed data in API

```
 NSDictionary *params=@{@"description":@"This is testing issue",
                               @"subject":@"Support needed..",
                               @"email":@"abc@gmail.com",
                               @"priority":[NSNumber numberWithInt:1],
                               @"status":[NSNumber numberWithInt:2]};

 [webServiceController PostWithHeaderUrlCall:@"https://test.freshdesk.com/api/v2/tickets" Param:params];
```

**WebServiceController.m**

```
-(void)PostWithHeaderUrlCall:(NSString *)IN_URL Param:(NSDictionary*) IN_Param
{

    AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];

    AFHTTPRequestSerializer *requestSerializer = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];
    NSData *basicAuthCredentials = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@",@"fsdwt52ewr5325wer5",@"x"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *base64AuthCredentials = [basicAuthCredentials base64EncodedStringWithOptions:(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions)0];
    [requestSerializer setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Basic %@", base64AuthCredentials] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
    manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes setByAddingObject:@"application/json"];

    manager.requestSerializer = requestSerializer;

    [manager POST:IN_URL parameters:IN_Param progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject)
     {
         m_Status=1;
         self.dic_Response = (NSDictionary *)responseObject;
         [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:m_strPostMsg object:self];

     } failure:^(NSURLSessionTask *operation, NSError *error) {
         m_Status=0;
         self.dic_Response=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
         [self.dic_Response setValue:Time_Out_Msg forKey:@"message"];
         NSLog(@"%@",error);
         [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:m_strPostMsg object:self];

     }];

}
```

Comment: which type of media you pass in web service ?

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya I passed Nsdictionary in parms nothing like image of mp3 file

Comment: I think issue is, I have to pass json in API parms

Comment: if you want to pass only textual data then you can also use NSMutableDictionary instead of Dictionary and its working fine . for me.

Comment: But this API accept Json data format @HimanshuMoradiya

Comment: did you find a solution ?

Comment: Use the AFJSONRequestSerializer for doing your request. That serializer will automatically convert your dictionary to the JSON format required by the API. Check out the docs: http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/2.0.0/Classes/AFJSONRequestSerializer.html

Answer (score 0):

**AFNetworking 3.0 use this code for pass data on server .**

```
 NSMutableDictionary *params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
 [params setValue:YOURV_VALUE forKey:@"description"];
 [params setValue:YOURV_VALUE forKey:@"subject"];
 [params setValue:YOURV_VALUE forKey:@"email"];
  [params setValue:YOURV_VALUE forKey:@"priority"];
[params setValue:YOURV_VALUE forKey:@"status"];

[webServiceController PostWithHeaderUrlCall:@"https://test.freshdesk.com/api/v2/tickets" Param:params];

-(void)PostWithHeaderUrlCall:(NSString *)IN_URL Param:(NSMutableDictionary*) _params
{
        AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:YOUR_URL]];
        manager.requestSerializer = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];
    manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"application/json", @"text/json", @"text/javascript",@"text/html", nil];
    [manager POST:url parameters:_params progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {
            NSLog(@"response = %@", responseObject);
        if( _success )
        {
            _success( responseObject ) ;
        }
        } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
            NSLog(@"error = %@", error);
            if( _failure )
            {
                _failure( error) ;
            }
        }];
    }
    else{
        [Utility showAlertWithMessage:@"No Internet Connection"];
    }
   }
 }
```

Comment: @YogendraPatel try new updated code just replace it with your one and check it.

Comment: just copy my method and replace it with your one and follow my tip . for pass your value at their pass your value. @YogendraPatel

Comment: in which line you got this error ? and are you using AFNetworking 3.0

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130178/discussion-between-yogendra-patel-and-himanshu-moradiya).